# Click a bar and select the corresponding JTabel record

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfreechart

I have a JScrollPane divided in two `Jpanel`s as you can see in the picture:

[image]

On the right there is a `JTable` with three columns. On the left there is the corresponding histogram created with `JFreeChart` API. 
I have to implement a listener on the histogram to ensure that when one presses on a bar, the corresponding record in the `JTable` on the left is selected.

To reach my target I implement this listener:

```
    chartPanel.addChartMouseListener(new ChartMouseListener() {

        @Override
        public void chartMouseMoved(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void chartMouseClicked(ChartMouseEvent arg0) {

            try{
            TableModel model = table.getModel();    
            CategoryItemEntity entity = (CategoryItemEntity) arg0.getEntity();
            Comparable row = entity.getRowKey();
            Comparable col = entity.getColumnKey();
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(row));
            String field = String.valueOf(col);

                for(int i = 0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                    if(model.getValueAt(i, 0).equals(field)) {
                        table.changeSelection(i, 0, false, false);

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("No bars selected");
            }


        }
    });
```

This listener works correctly until one orders the JTable by clicking on the header. For example, if one orders the JTable according to `Number of occurrences`, when one presses a bar of the histogram, the selected row in the `JTable` does not correspond to the clicked bar.

---Edit

When one presses a bar, I have to selected the correspondig record in the JTable. For example, suppose one presses "Bronx" bar:

[image]

My code works correctly until one orders the JTable by clicking on the header field (borough, type, Number of Occurrences).

Comment: I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must convert the view row number to exact row number.

You can do this by:

```
int realRowNumber = table.convertRowIndexToModel(viewRowIndex);
```